# nginx get real ip client

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, nginx-config

I use Nginx, Angular and Spring Boot.

I can't get the client's real IP address. I keep getting 127.0.0.1

Cloudflare acts as DNS.

I am testing all this on a local Windows computer. I make all requests to the server (to the local computer) via VPN or via phone.

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve the problem?

```
    worker_processes  1;



    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }



    http {


        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        ssl_certificate ./ssl/my-sert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ./ssl/my-key.key;

        upstream apispring {
                server 127.0.0.1:8080;
            }


         server {


            listen              443 ssl;
            server_name  apis.sad.com;  

                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                 #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


                 // https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-restore-real-ip-address-when-behind-a-reverse-proxy/
                 proxy_set_header CF-Connecting-IP $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


            location / {
                 proxy_pass http://apispring;
             }



         }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider some network infrastructure basics when we talk about IP addresses and client's addresses. There is no problem, `localhost` is just the address of the current machine. Use cmd `ipconfig` to get the local IPv4 address.

**Short answer:** Your client/Windows machine you are running the web app on has either (1) the `localhost:8080` address or (2) the DHCP IPv4 local `192.168.1.100/xxx:8080` address from your home. Use https://www.whatsmyip.org/ to get your geographically assigned ISP IP of your household.

**Long answer**

**First about network addresses in general**: You have (1) the internet protocol address and you have the (2) port address. An IP address is linked directly to the host/machine. The port after the IP address is linked directly to the process or service running on that machine.

You have three levels of IP addresses you can have:

**1 The localhost level** If you connect to `127.0.0.1`, you're basically telling the computer to connect to itself. If you run your web app on that specific same computer you work on, the address will always be `localhost`. And when you run your web app, the address will be `localhost:8080`.

**2 Local network level** Each local network has it's own DHCP mechanism, meaning devices are managed and identified by the local router instead of the internet. These are normally done through `192.168.1.100` address books. Each device in your own network get's assigned such a unique address. You can look these addresses up on the machine itself or on the router settings, and if you deploy your app on a certain machine, the address to connect to will get `192.168.1.100:8080`.

**3 Internet level** RIRs manage IP address geographically, and for instance, you as a household get such IP address from the ISP (the IP you get from https://www.whatsmyip.org/ for instance). If you want to connect to your home from outside internet, you would need this address. If you have port forwarding on the router connected to your ISP, and you configure port forwarding, you can route ISP IP `226.124.59.27` to local machine IP `192.168.1.102:8080`.